# Sinon crypto stub for method within a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I'm trying to test a simple function that generates a random name using the nodejs crypto library. I'm using sinon to stub out a method call within the callback of pseudoRandomBytes but the stub doesn't seem to be called. Example:

#### getFileName.js

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = (req, file, cb) => {
  crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(32, (err, raw) => {
    try{
      cb(err, err ? undefined : crypto.createHash('MD5').update(raw).digest('hex'));
    } catch(err) {
      cb(err);
    }
  });
};
```

#### Test (running in mocha)

```
it('Crypto Error: createHash', function () {
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  const expectedError = new Error('stub error occurred');
  let cryptoStub = sinon.stub(crypto, 'createHash').throws(expectedError);
  let callback = sinon.spy();

  getFileName(null, null, callback);

  cryptoStub.restore();
  sinon.assert.calledWith(callback, expectedError);
});
```

I would expect the above test to throw once `createHash` gets called. If I move the `crypto.createHash` call outside of the callback (before the pseudoRandomNumber call) it works just fine. I a bit of a newbie so my basic understanding of what sinon and nodejs are doing could be completely wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What test framework do you use?

Comment: I am using mocha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it seems like `createHash()` wasn't called was because you were making an assertion before the callback call was complete due to asynchronous function.

Promise with async/await will work. Another method which doesn't involve changing your module to use promise is to do your assertions within the callback.

```
it('Crypto Error: createHash', function (done) {
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  const expectedError = new Error('stub error occurred');
  let cryptoStub = sinon.stub(crypto, 'createHash').throws(expectedError);

  getFileName(null, null, function (err, hash) {
    sinon.assert.match(err, expectedError);
    cryptoStub.restore();
    done();
  });
});
```

This way, you can check that the callback is called with the expected error. One way to confirm this is you can change line 4 to `.throws('some other error')` and the test will fail.

Comment: it is true that asserting in the callback does not involve updating his module, however I Would strongly recommend to move his code to work with promises. Not only for testing (it will generate cleaner code) but also for whenever he uses his module - otherwise it will be harder to make subsequent calls without involving spagetti code

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I agree. Just that the question specifically mentioned callback.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [crypto.pseudoRandomBytes()](https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/crypto/#cryptorandombytessize-callback) is an async function, so the rest of your test code executes before your callback. That way, your stub is restored before your function is actually used it.

In order to make it properly work, you should update your `getFileName.js` so it returns a promise - that way you can [await it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
module.exports = (req, file, cb) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(32, (err, raw) => {
            try{
                cb(err, err ? undefined : crypto.createHash('MD5').update(raw).digest('hex'));
                resolve();
            } catch(err) {
              reject(cb(err));
            }
        });
    });
};
```

and then in your test

```
// added async
it('Crypto Error: createHash', async () => {
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  const expectedError = new Error('stub error occurred');
  let cryptoStub = sinon.stub(crypto, 'createHash').throws(expectedError);
  let callback = sinon.spy();

  await getFileName(null, null, callback);
  // once we are here, the callback has already been executed and the promise that getFileName resolved.
  cryptoStub.restore();
  sinon.assert.calledWith(callback, expectedError);
});
```